# Расположить элементы в QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Отправляю в `QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()` две таблицы и график. Нужно чтоб они шли ровно, но всё разъезжается.

**app.py**

```
from UI_test import Ui_Form
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import qdarkgraystyle
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkgraystyle.load_stylesheet())
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UI_test.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt,QPointF
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(1500, 900)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        
        window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(window2, 'Explore')
        self.table_anno = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_anno.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_anno.setFixedWidth(280)
        self.table_anno.setFixedHeight(150)
        self.table_anno.rowCount()
        self.table_anno.columnCount()
        self.table_anno.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Класс', 'Фигура', 'Лейбл','Del'])
        header = self.table_anno.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.hide()


        self.table_classes = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_classes.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_classes.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Название класса', 'Цвет', 'Удалить'])
        header_class = self.table_classes.horizontalHeader()
        header_class.hide()

        self.table_classes.setFixedWidth(230)
        self.table_classes.setFixedHeight(150)
        self.table_classes.setColumnWidth(2, 50)
        self.table_classes.setColumnWidth(1, 50)

        self.add_class_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("New class")
        self.add_class_button.setFixedWidth(80)
        self.add_class_button.setFixedHeight(25)

        self.add_label_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add label")
        self.add_label_button.setFixedWidth(80)
        self.add_label_button.setFixedHeight(25)

        table_class_v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        table_class_v_box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        table_class_v_box.addWidget(self.add_class_button)
        table_class_v_box.addWidget(self.table_classes)


        table_anno_v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        table_anno_v_box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        table_anno_v_box.addWidget(self.add_label_button)
        table_anno_v_box.addWidget(self.table_anno)



        table_class_panel_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        table_class_panel_frame.setLayout(table_class_v_box)
        table_anno_panel_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        table_anno_panel_frame.setLayout(table_anno_v_box)

        self.chart_m = QtCharts.QChart()
        self.series_m = QtCharts.QAreaSeries()
        self.chart_m.addSeries(self.series_m)
        self.chart_m.createDefaultAxes()

        self.chart_m.axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setTickCount(10)
        self.chart_m.axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].setTickCount(10)

        self.chartView_m = QtCharts.QChartView(self.chart_m)
        self.chartView_m.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.chartView_m.setFixedHeight(230)



        main_h_box_exp = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        main_h_box_exp.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        main_h_box_exp.addWidget(table_class_panel_frame)
        main_h_box_exp.addWidget(table_anno_panel_frame)
        main_h_box_exp.addWidget(self.chartView_m)

        container_exp = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container_exp.setLayout(main_h_box_exp)
        window2.setCentralWidget(container_exp)

        self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не совсем понял как вы хотите разместить виджеты, поэтому разместил как понимал.

Обратите внимание

> void QBoxLayout::**addStretch**(int stretch = 0)
>
> Добавляет растягиваемое пространство (QSpacerItem) с нулевым минимальным размером
> и коэффициентом растяжения до конца этого макета блока.

Также мне кажется, что вы злоупотребляете с использование `setFixedWidth` и `setFixedHeight`

```
import sys
# import qdarkgraystyle
'''
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt,QPointF
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts
'''
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChartView, QChart, QBarSeries, QBarSet, \
    QBarCategoryAxis, QAreaSeries
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from UI_test import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
#        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(1500, 900)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        
        window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(window2, 'Explore')
        
        self.table_anno = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 4)                                     # 4, 4 
        self.table_anno.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_anno.setFixedWidth(280)
        self.table_anno.setFixedHeight(150)
        self.table_anno.rowCount()
        self.table_anno.columnCount()
        self.table_anno.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Класс', 'Фигура', 'Лейбл','Del'])
        
        header = self.table_anno.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.hide()

        self.table_classes = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 3)                                   # 4, 3 
        self.table_classes.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_classes.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Название класса', 'Цвет', 'Удалить'])
        header_class = self.table_classes.horizontalHeader()
        header_class.hide()
        self.table_classes.setFixedWidth(230)
        self.table_classes.setFixedHeight(150)
        self.table_classes.setColumnWidth(2, 50)
        self.table_classes.setColumnWidth(1, 50)

        self.add_class_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("New class")
        self.add_class_button.clicked.connect(lambda: print('New class'))                #
        self.add_class_button.setFixedWidth(80)
        self.add_class_button.setFixedHeight(25)

        self.add_label_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add label")
        self.add_label_button.clicked.connect(lambda: print('Add label'))                #
        self.add_label_button.setFixedWidth(80)
        self.add_label_button.setFixedHeight(25)

        table_class_v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        table_class_v_box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        table_class_v_box.addWidget(self.add_class_button)
        table_class_v_box.addWidget(self.table_classes)
        table_class_v_box.addStretch()                                              # +++

        table_anno_v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        table_anno_v_box.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        table_anno_v_box.addWidget(self.add_label_button)
        table_anno_v_box.addWidget(self.table_anno)
        table_anno_v_box.addStretch()                                               # +++
        
        table_class_panel_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        table_class_panel_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: #c3c3c3;')         #
        table_class_panel_frame.setLayout(table_class_v_box)
        table_anno_panel_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        table_anno_panel_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: #c3c3f3;')          #
        table_anno_panel_frame.setLayout(table_anno_v_box)

        self.chart_m = QChart()
        self.series_m = QAreaSeries()
        self.chart_m.addSeries(self.series_m)
        self.chart_m.createDefaultAxes()

        self.chart_m.axes(Qt.Horizontal)[0].setTickCount(10)
        self.chart_m.axes(Qt.Vertical)[0].setTickCount(10)

        self.chartView_m = QChartView(self.chart_m)
#        self.chartView_m.setFixedWidth(300)
#        self.chartView_m.setFixedHeight(230)        
        self.chartView_m.setMinimumWidth(300)            # ?
        self.chartView_m.setMinimumHeight(230)           # ?

        main_h_box_exp = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        main_h_box_exp.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        main_h_box_exp.addWidget(table_class_panel_frame)
        main_h_box_exp.addWidget(table_anno_panel_frame)
        main_h_box_exp.addWidget(self.chartView_m, stretch=1)                   # stretch=1
        main_h_box_exp.addStretch()                                             # +++

        container_exp = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container_exp.setLayout(main_h_box_exp)
        
        window2.setCentralWidget(container_exp)

        self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
#    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkgraystyle.load_stylesheet())
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понял Вас! Огромное спасибо за помощь!